# How to print an Array of Object in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, object

In my JavaScript file I create this array:

```
const get_rows = () => {
            return document.getElementById("section-content").querySelectorAll('.element');
}
( get_rows() ).forEach( ( item, index ) => {
            currentOrder[ item.id ] = index;
})
```

When I pass this array(currentOrder) in PHP by ajax, I try to print it, but it gives me

```
[object Object]
```

So, how can i print in PHP an array of object? thanks

Comment: hi, you can't pass an object like that to php. You have to serialize it first to a string (the only type php handles for GET or POST parameters). You may use `JSON.stringify` for that purpose

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to give you answer, but because there is no proper explanation so it is quite difficult to understand the proper issue.
What I find in your case is, you are not defined currentOrder. I just implemented a small code with html for you.

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="section-content">
<div id="id1" class="element">hi</div>
<div id="id2" class="element">hi1</div>
<div id="id3" class="element">hi2</div>

</div>
<script>
console.log("hi");
 const get_rows = () => {
    return document.getElementById("section-content").querySelectorAll('.element');
 }
 
 var currentOrder = [];
 ( get_rows() ).forEach( ( item, index ) => {
    currentOrder[item.id] = index;
    
 })

 console.log(currentOrder);
 // Here you have to send currentOrder to your php code.
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Second thing is, why you are getting "index" in your array, Its just index of your element inside section-content.
If still you have any problem please try to share more code snippets to help us to answer properly.